# Dual Partion windows not working ?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, wubi

I originally set up Ubuntu "along side" widows(Vista) and realized it was done though wubi after I tried to set up a VB and didn't have enough room.  I then repartitioned the HD and did a stand alone Ubuntu install.  The problem is when I try to boot windows it starts to load then does a flash and heads back to the start up boot page with ubuntu and windows on the boot screen.  Ubuntu loads fine, everytime but windows goes back.  Here is the boot script info.  http://paste.ubuntu.com/6405545/

Any help would be appreciated. I want to leave windows behind but still need it for some things on this machine.

Comment: Are you booting Windows on `/dev/sda1`? That's the one you should be choosing. Note that the boot flag is on `/dev/sda2` - it should be on `/dev/sda1` (but this shouldn't cause the problem as you are booting from Grub).

Comment: Another thing, if you let the Ubuntu installer split your Windows partition, you may need to boot a Windows repair CD and let it run the repair.